# Why value of datepicker input field disappear after click on next element in robotframework testing?

Tags: javascript, selenium, datepicker, material-ui, robotframework

I am filling fields in web application with selenium robot framework. When robot fills up input field for datepicker materialui it works fine but after it clicks on next element (e.g.: radiabutton, textfield...) the value of input field clears itself. Please Help me I can not find any solution for this problem :(

```
Execute Javascript   
    document.getElementById('estimated_start').value='June 6, 2019'  #this is input field
Execute Javascript  
    document.getElementById('estimated_end_date').value='August 30, 2019'  #this is input field
Click Element       xpath=//div[contains(text(),'Yes')]   #this is radiobutton, when it comes here above fields are cleared
```

when I am filling field manualy this is how input look like...value is set

```
<input type="text" style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: medium none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: inherit; font: inherit; height: 100%;" id="estimated_start" value="June 6, 2019">
```

when robot filling the input value is cleared after datepicker input lost focus

```
<input type="text" id="estimated_start" value style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: none; outline: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: inherit; font: inherit; opacity: 1; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); height: 100%;">
```

Comment: it's clear and display as mm/dd/yyyy, right ?

Comment: @SidaraKEO in fact required format is MMM d, yyyyy so date I set as value should be correct (August 30, 2019), but field is completly clear it displays nothing afterwards